# What's the best way to insert columns in a pandas Dataframe when you don't know the exact number of columns?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have an input dataframe.

I have also a list, with the same `len` as the number of rows in the dataframe.

Every element of the list is a dictionary: the key is the name of the new column, and the value is the value to be inserted in the cell.

I have to insert the columns from that list in the dataframe.

What is the best way to do so?

So far, given the input dataframe `indf` and the list `l`, I came up with something on the line of:

```
from copy import deepcopy
outdf = deepcopy(indf)
for index, row in indf.iterrows():
    e = l[index]
    for key, value in e:
        outdf.loc[index, key] = value
```

But it doesn't seem pythonic and pandasnic and I get performance warnings like:

```
<ipython-input-5-9dde586a9c14>:8: PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead.  To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`
```

Answer (score 1):

If the sorting of the list and the data frame is the same, you can convert your list of dictionaries to a data frame:

```
mylist = [
    {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3},
    {'e':11,'f':22,'c':33},
    {'a':111,'b':222,'c':333}
]

mylist_df = pd.DataFrame(mylist)
```

|  | a | b | c | e | f |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | nan | nan |
| 1 | nan | nan | 33 | 11 | 22 |
| 2 | 111 | 222 | 333 | nan | nan |

Then you can use `pd.concat` to merge the list to your input data frame:

```
result = pd.concat([input_df, mylist_df], axis=1)
```

In this way, there is always a column created for all unique keys in your dictionary, regardless of they exist in one dictionary and not the other.